# python 3 - combine channels function return wrong

Tags: python

A few days ago I asked for help here about an assignment that we have. Part of the assignment was to build a function that receives a three-dimension list,  with two dimension list, built from single color channels, and to combine it into one colorful image.

This is the function:

```
def combine_channels(image):
new_channel = []
for row_pairs in zip(*image):
    new_channel.append([channel_combined for channel_combined in zip(*row_pairs)])
return new_channel
```

its supposed to recieve this:

`combine_channels([[[1]], [[2]]])`

and return this: `[[[1, 2]]]`

but instead, its return this:`[[(1, 2)]]`

Does someone know how to change the () to []? I've been told before but sadly I didn't get it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Convert the tuple to a list:

```py
def combine_channels(image):
    new_channel = []
    for row_pairs in zip(*image):
        new_channel.append([list(channel_combined) for channel_combined in zip(*row_pairs)])
    return new_channel
```

Comment: But its already a list, type(new_channel) return a class "list"

Comment: Look at the code I posted above. `channel_combined` is a tuple and you need to convert it to a list in the context of the list comprehension.

Comment: Ohh now I saw. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. Please "accept" the answer. Instructions can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers